# Multiple iphoto slideshows on multiple monitors

Tags: iphoto

I have a 3 monitor setup and would like to run slideshows from 3 different albums on the different monitors.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

the iphoto allow you to use only one monitor where primary window is open,
but

I'd like to poit you to this:
 http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/Freeware/SlideShowforErik.shtml

possibly it helps